# How do I get the same share buttons that's present on workonlineblog.com, towards the left hand side when you view any post?

Tags: wordpress, sharing

How do I use the same share buttons that's present on [workonlineblog.com](http://workonlineblog.com), towards the left hand side when you view any post? I'm not referring to the round share buttons but the square share buttons shown on the left hand side of the page.

Comment: In general, questions here need to be (a) reasonably self-contained, so that the question remains useful even if the link breaks, and (b) feature code you've tried, so we can see you've made a prior effort, and so we can see what in particular you are getting stuck on. For the first point, if you can edit in a screenshot, that would be useful. Bear in mind that answers are intended for readers in perpetuity, not just for the person who asks a question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind for when I have another question. In the mean while it seems SciPhi has answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icons you are referring to come from the [AddThis Sharing plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/addthis/) for WordPress